# Right-continuous supermatingale

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-analysis

Considering a right-continuous sub-martingale $X$ bounded in $L^1,$ in theorem $33,$ it's possible to write $X$ as the difference of two positive right-continuous super-martingales.

The proof refers to $9$ (picture) for a proof, to obtain right-continuity he wrote: "taking right limits along the rationals".

How to explain this ? I tried to take $Y'_u =\inf_{r \in \mathbb{Q} \cap ]u,\infty[} Y_r$ (Helly theorem uses this form to obtain a right-continuous function), in this case $Y_u'$ is not super-martingale (at least it's not measurable $\mathcal{F}_u$).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take $Y'_t:=\liminf_{r\downarrow t,r\in\Bbb Q}Y_r$. This process is everywhere defined, adapted, and $Y'_t=\lim_{s\downarrow t}Y_s$ for all $t\ge 0$ a.s.

Comment: It should be noted that $Y_t'$ is adapted because the filtration is right-continuous: this is why we assume the filtration satisfies the usual conditions.

Comment: @JohnDawkins $Y'$ in your definition is it a super-martingale?

Comment: Can't we proceed without the right-continuity of the filtration?

Comment: In the page of D&M that you have quoted, $Y$ is a  martingale, hence so it $Y'$. Without the right-continuity of $(\mathcal F_t)$, $Y'_t$ will only be $\mathcal F_{t+}$-measurable.

Comment: What property do we need to obtain that $Y'$ is a martingale? (we are taking the $\liminf Y$)

Comment: I used $\liminf$ only to ensure that $Y'_t$ is precisely defined for each sample point. The important thing is that  because $(Y_t)$ is a martingale, the backward martingale convergence theorem implies that $\lim_{r\downarrow t,r\in\Bbb Q}Y_r$ exists a.s and in $L^1$; the $L^1$ convergence then implies that $E[Y'_t\mid\mathcal F_s]=Y_s$ a.s. for each $0\le s\le t$. This fact and the  right continuity of $(\mathcal F_t)$ (which implies that $Y'_s$ is $\mathcal F_s$-measurable) yield $Y'_s=Y_s$ a.s., and so $E[Y'_t\mid\mathcal F_s]=Y'_s$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins hopefully this is not late, the defined $Y',$ why are they right-continuous ?

Comment: For a.e sample point $\omega$ you have $Y'_t(\omega) =\lim_{r\downarrow t,r\in\Bbb Q} Y_r(\omega)$ for all $t\ge 0$. Fix such an $\omega$ and fix $t$. Given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $r\in\Bbb Q\cap[t,t+\delta)$ then $|Y'_t(\omega)-Y_r(\omega)|<\epsilon$. This implies that if  $s\in(t,t+\delta)$ then  
$$
|Y'_t(\omega)-Y'_s(\omega)|\le \epsilon.
$$
It follows that $\lim_{s\downarrow t}Y'_s(\omega) =Y'_t(\omega)$.

Comment: Usually is $Y'$ right-continuous ? (Without using almost sure convergence)